# Callback when an element of a ListView is visible

Tags: android, events, android-listview

I have a ListView full of views, some of them are out the window, and I can access to them scrolling with my finger.

Is there a callback, or an event fired when, during the scroll, I show a particular element previously "hidden" down?

ps: Each of the elements of the ListView has different heights

Comment: When `getView` is called it means that the item is visible

Answer (score 1):

Android will call `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` as soon as the items is visible. You can use that as a callback.

You can create an interface like:

```
public interface OnItemVisible{
    public void onVisible(int position);
}
```

Pass it to your adapter's constructor and call it on `getView` like:

```
if(mMyCallback!=null){
    mMyCallback.onVisible(position); //where position is the getView parameter
}
```

Comment: umm... I updated my adapter to implements the Interface you suggested, but the callback is fired at the start of the activity, not when the element I'm looking for is visible... is there some kind of adapter to use as base?

Comment: Ofc it's fired at the start of activity. Because the first elements are visible. That's why it is fired.

Comment: umm... I see the callback is fired with *all* my elements, also the last ones

Comment: How could the last ones be called? If that would happen the listview would be displaying them.